# Validation Rule to trigger when Account is made Active and following fields are not blank based on a record type

Tags: validation-rule

can I get some advise on below validation rule on Account? I have tried to change it multiple times, but it's not firing when it should.

When the User is trying to make an Account Active by unchecking inactive field, each different fields are required for each record to be checked if BLANK.

I'd also like to check if below is correct - val rule should fire when the value is either O or greater than 1
**Count_of_Terms__c >=1**

With record type IDs - should I remove last 3 digits?

My Validation Rule:

```
AND(
    NOT($Setup.Bypass_Settings__c.Validations__c),
    ISCHANGED(Inactive__c)

    /*RT 1*/
    AND(
        RecordTypeId = "0123X0000004FkY",
        OR(
            ISBLANK(Business_Name__c),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAAccountTradingCurrency__c),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAAccountsPayableControl__r.Name),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAAccountsReceivableControl__r.Name), 
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODABankAccountName__c),
            ISBLANK(BillingStreet), 
            ISBLANK(BillingPostalCode),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAInvoiceEmail__c), 
            ISBLANK(TEXT(c2g__CODAPaymentMethod__c),
            ISBLANK(TEXT(c2g__CODAVATStatus__c),
            Count_of_Terms__c = 0
        )
    ),

    /*RT 2*/
    AND(
        RecordTypeId = "0123X000000446Q",
        OR(
            ISBLANK(Business_Name__c),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAAccountTradingCurrency__c),
            ISBLANK( c2g__CODAAccountsReceivableControl__r.Name), 
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODABankAccountName__c),
            ISBLANK(BillingStreet), 
            ISBLANK(BillingPostalCode),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAInvoiceEmail__c), 
            ISBLANK(TEXT(c2g__CODAVATStatus__c)
        )
    ),

    /*RT 3*/
    AND(
        RecordTypeId = "0123X000000446R",
        OR(
            ISBLANK(Business_Name__c),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAAccountTradingCurrency__c),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAAccountsPayableControl__r.Name),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODABankAccountName__c),
            ISBLANK(BillingStreet), 
            ISBLANK(BillingPostalCode),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAInvoiceEmail__c), 
            ISBLANK(TEXT(c2g__CODAPaymentMethod__c),
            ISBLANK(TEXT(c2g__CODAVATStatus__c),
            Count_of_Terms__c = 0
        )
    ),

    /*RT 4*/
    AND(
        RecordTypeId = "0123X000000446S",
        OR(
            ISBLANK(Business_Name__c),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAAccountTradingCurrency__c),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAAccountsPayableControl__r.Name),
            ISBLANK( c2g__CODAAccountsReceivableControl__r.Name), 
            ISBLANK(BillingStreet), 
            ISBLANK(BillingPostalCode),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAInvoiceEmail__c), 
            ISBLANK(TEXT(c2g__CODAVATStatus__c)
        )
    ),

    /*RT 5*/
    AND(
        RecordTypeId = "0123X0000004FkY",
        OR(
            ISBLANK(Business_Name__c),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAAccountTradingCurrency__c),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAAccountsPayableControl__r.Name),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODABankAccountName__c),
            ISBLANK(BillingStreet),
            ISBLANK(BillingPostalCode),
            ISBLANK(c2g__CODAInvoiceEmail__c), 
            ISBLANK(TEXT(c2g__CODAPaymentMethod__c),
            ISBLANK(TEXT(c2g__CODAVATStatus__c),
            Count_of_Terms__c  = 0
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Use RecordType.DeveloperName, not ids - also - 1 record can only be 1 RT yet you are using an outer AND - hence four of the five inner ANDs will be false, making the outer AND false

Comment: Can you please advise where to put/remove the outer AND to make this validation rule work on all conditions and a particular record will only check if the account is inactive and then look for a condition relevant to that record?  @cropredy

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because  1 record can only be 1 RT yet you are using an outer AND - hence four of the five inner ANDs will be false, making the outer AND false

You'll need to do something like this

```
AND (
    NOT($Setup.Bypass_Settings__c.Validations__c),
    ISCHANGED(Inactive__c),  /* Inactive field changed */   
    NOT(Inactive__c),        /* changed to unchecked */
    OR (
        AND(
            RecordType.DeveloperName = 'RT1',
            OR ( ...  /* fields can't be blank */
            )
        ),
        AND(
            RecordType.DeveloperName = 'RT2',
            OR ( ...  /* diff fields can't be blank */
            )
        ),       
        ...
     )  /* end of RT variations */
 )
```

**Pro tip**: Complex validation rules are best developed/ debugged incrementally - verify it works for a single recordtype, 1 non-blank, 1 blank field; then add more field checks; then add second recordtype, etc.  Use comments in your VR as doc

Comment: Thank you @cropredy - I managed to figure out what it was :D I missing two parenthesis on below fields   ISBLANK(TEXT(c2g__CODAPaymentMethod__c)),
     ISBLANK(TEXT(c2g__CODAVATStatus__c))